# tikz: setting up a spring

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I am trying to set up a spring command but keep receiving the message:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key
  '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrentname ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps
  you misspelled it.
```

The code I have is:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration = coil,
  spring/.style = {
    decoration = {
      pre length = #1,
      post length = #1}
  }]
  \fill[pattern = north east lines] (-2cm, 0) coordinate (A) rectangle
  (2cm, 0.25cm);
  \draw (A) -- (2cm, 0);
  \draw[decorate, spring = 0.15cm] (-1cm, 0) -- (-1cm, -1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Everything is spelled correctly so I am not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration = coil,
  spring/.style = {
    decoration = {
      pre length = #1,
      post length = #1}
  }]
  \fill[pattern = north east lines] (-2cm, 0) coordinate (A) rectangle
  (2cm, 0.25cm);
  \draw (A) -- (2cm, 0);
  \draw[decorate, spring = 0.15cm] (-1cm, 0) -- (-1cm, -1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am looking at the manual for 3.0.0 and it says to just load decoration for coil, snake, etc

Comment: @dustin Which page?

Comment: From the top of page 353 down to page 357

Comment: @dustin It doesn't discuss about coil. Does it? ;-)  `coil` comes under `decorations.pathmorphing` library.

Comment: The examples are about coil though.

Comment: @dustin Not explicitly. It is more general and `coil` is not general. Read section 48.2, page 586, and coil comes in page 588.