# LaTeX stanli package. How to design a spring element?

Tags: tikz-pgf, stanli

The documentation for the `stanli` package can be found here: /https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/stanli/stanli.pdf

And the documentation for the design of a spring, can be found here: [tikz: setting up a spring](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198443/tikz-setting-up-a-spring)

I have a straightforward question:

The command: `\support{5}{b}` in the `stanli` package can introduce a spring with a support. I want a spring between two nodes. How can I extend the `stanli` package to code a spring?

Based on a suggestion, in one of the answers below, I made:

```
%preamble definition 
\makeatletter 
\newcommandx{\nodespring}[2][]{%
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={#2:(#1)}]
        \draw [spring] (#1) -- (#2);
\end{scope}}
\makeatother
```

However, in the implementation:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\point{a}{0}{0}
\point{b}{5}{0}
\nodespring{a}{b}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get an error:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `b' (in 'b'). \nodespring{a}{b}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example.  I note that the package is available via ctan.org

Comment: Unrelated: What physical sense makes a free spring?

Comment: Modified the question to mean "introduce a spring between two nodes".

Comment: I guess that your problem is solved, since you accepted my answer. But just for the record, your definition of `\nodespring` is incorrect. See, you're trying to make a spring between node `a` and node `b`, thus they are *nodes*! But in the optional argument to `\begin{scope}` you have `rotate around={#2:(#1)}`, which means "rotate this #2 degrees around #1". But remember, both `#1` and `#2` are nodes, so your command is telling PGF to rotate "rotate this `node b` degrees around `node a`". Doesn't make much sense, right?

Comment: (continuation) To fix this you can, for instance, use: `\newcommandx{\nodespring}[3][3=0]{%
\begin{scope}[rotate around={#3:(#1)}]
\draw [spring] (#1) -- (#2);
\end{scope}}`, which will make a third optional argument, which defaults to `0` degrees. But you are trying to draw a beam, so a rotation around a node doesn't make much sense either, so you can fall back to: `\newcommandx{\nodespring}[2]{%
\begin{scope}
\draw [spring] (#1) -- (#2);
\end{scope}}`. Which is basically what I have in my answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Edit:

#### A spring between two nodes

The `stanli` package defines a line type which has a `zigzag` decoraiton and calls it `spring`. This style, though, is not "customizable" except by redefining the macros `\springPreLength`, `\springPostLength`, `\springSegmentLength`, and `\springAmplitude`.

It's probably of no harm if we redefine the style to add an argument to it:

```
\tikzstyle{spring} = [
  normalLine,
  decoration=
    {
      zigzag,
      pre length=\springPreLength,
      post length=\springPostLength,
      segment length=\springSegmentLength,
      amplitude=\springAmplitude,
      #1
    },
    decorate,
]
```

then create a command that uses this style:

```
\newcommandx{\spring}[3][3=]{%
  \begin{scope}
    \draw [spring={#3}] (#1) -- (#2);
  \end{scope}}
```

you just put these in your preamble *after* you load `stanli`,

Now we can replace any beam, for example, `\beam{2}{g}{h};` by `\spring{g}{h};`. We can also add an optional argument to the `\spring` command to change its appearance: `\spring{g}{h}[amplitude=1mm];`.

Doing so in the example structure from the documentation:

> [image]

## Previous answer:

The definition of the spring from the package is:

```
  \begin{scope}[rotate around={#3:(#2)}]
    \draw [spring] (#2) -- ++(0,-\springLength);
    \draw [normalLine] ($(#2)+1*(\supportBasicLength/2,-\springLength)$) -- ++(-\supportBasicLength,0);
    \clip ($(#2)+1*(-\supportBasicLength/2,-\supportBasicHeight-\springLength)$) rectangle ($(#2)+1*(\supportBasicLength/2,-\springLength)$);
    \draw[hatching]($(#2)+1*(\supportHatchingLength/2,-\springLength)$) -- ++(-\supportHatchingLength,0);
  \end{scope}
```

The part that we need for the "free spring" is just the first line, so we can either create a command:

```
\newcommandx{\freespring}[2][2=0]{%
  \begin{scope}[rotate around={#2:(#1)}]
    \draw [spring] (#1) -- ++(0,-\springLength);
  \end{scope}}
```

and use as `\freespring{b};`, or we can patch the `\support` command to add the new type:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\apptocmd\csname\string\support\endcsname
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{7}}{%
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={#3:(#2)}]
      \draw [spring] (#2) -- ++(0,-\springLength);
    \end{scope}
  }{}%
  }%
  {}{}
```

which can be used as `\support{7}{b};`. Both give the same result. The picture from the cover of the documentation becomes:

> [image]

Comment: Could this solution be extended to mean a spring between two nodes?

Comment: @Indian Edited my answer to have a spring between two nodes.